# Unable to select date in datepicker

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I'm testing a widget where I have to enter a start and end date using a calender. In real life use I select the option to enter dates from a drop down, a calender then appears where I have to click a start and an end date. Only after I click on 2 days the date fields are filled. I have no problems doing this manualy but automating the test is proofing difficult. Here's a few screenshots to illustrate what I'm trying to do. After selecting the option to enter dates the following screen appears:

[image]

Here I first click the From day (24), followed by the To day (31). Right after I click 31 the calender dissappears and the two date fields are filled with my selection:

[image]

I'm trying to automate this with the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@class='DateRangePicker__DateLabel'][contains(text(), '24')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@class='DateRangePicker__DateLabel'][contains(text(), '31')]")).click();
```

Here's part of the code I'm basing this on:

```
<span class="DateRangePicker__DateLabel" data-reactid=".0.1.1.0.1.1.1.0.0.2.0.1:$0-2016-4.1.1.$4.$1.2">24</span>
```

The code does not fail but the dates are not selected either.

Comment: can you validate that the element is displayed before clicking on it. It ensures that the element is selectable.

Comment: Can you let me know how I can check this?

Comment: Are you sure that the code does not fail?  Perhaps you have a try/catch block which is swallowing a NullPointerException, or any other error that couldn't find an element?  @VigneshParamasivam is probably on the right track that you should wait for the elements to be visible before attempting to click it.

Answer (score 0):

using datepicker in selenium - [LINK](http://www.mythoughts.co.in/2013/04/selecting-date-from-datepicker-using.html#.V0RXf5F96Uk)

Comment: this answer will go invalid if the link gets broken, code sample/way of doing should suffice.

Comment: this answer will go invalid if the link gets broken ??? that link is to get the main idea about handling date pickers in selenium.

Comment: even though it provides any idea to solve the issue, it doesn't fit into SO answers definition. so what if the content gets moved to different page/structure? what if the site went down? will i be waiting until the site is up to get to see what i want? makes sense?

Comment: I tried following the code in the link (had to change some of it as the date is not a linktext) but this too does not work. Same as my own code, no errors but the dates are not selected either.

Answer (score 0):

You could inspect id of from and to field. THen execute this command using javascript

```
$('#id').datepicker("setDate", "date_you_want_in_right_format")
```

Note 1: You need to follow strictly date format that allowed by datePicker

Note 2: Tested with https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", "03/15/2016")
```

Comment: Thank you but I would like to actualy click the date instead of entering a date in the field. I want the script to replicate actual user actions.

Comment: please post the code snipet for yourp age. I could help to you. I already write exactly like you want before changing to my proposed method above.